# For fixed positive integers $a,k$ prove that there are infinitely many primes $p$ for which $p\equiv 1\pmod{k}$ and $a$ is a $k$'th power mod $p$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials

> For fixed positive integers $a$ and $k$, prove that there are infinitely many primes $p$ for which $p\equiv 1\pmod{k}$  and $a$ is a $k$th power modulo $p$.

I know that this problem could be solved by considering the $k$'th cyclotomic polynomial, but I don't know how.

Comment: Clarification requested:  Suppose that $a,k = 6,8$ respectively, and that $p$ is some satisfying prime number.  Does this mean that there exists some positive integer $b$ such that $b^8 \equiv 6\pmod{p}$?  In other words, do you intend that for any satisfying prime $p$, there exists *some* $b$ such that $b^k \equiv a\pmod{p}$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I intended by "$p$ is some satisfying prime number".  That there would be an infinite number of satisfying prime numbers, but that not all primes would be satisfying.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding you.The answer to your question is yes.

Comment: Where does this problem come from? How much (and what kind) of number theory do you know?

Comment: It comes from an article about cyclotomic polynomials.I know NT at a IMO level,and the basics of Galois theory,if that helps.

Comment: The body of your post should be self-contained. "What the title says" is not it. You don't start letters on the envelope, you don't start posts on the Subject line. It's  not that hard to include the problem in the body of the post.

Comment: I'm sorry,it is my second post so I'm not used to write appropriate titles.But you're right,thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: I found a much simpler proof. I’ll let the old one stay at the end of the post, but this one is much better.

As in the old proof, let $K$ be the splitting field of the polynomial $x^k-a$, let $\alpha$ be a primitive element that is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$ and $f$ be its (monic) minimal polynomial.

$K$ contains a primitive $k$-th root of unity so there are rational polynomials $A,B$ such that $\Phi_{k}(A(x))=B(x)f(x)$. $K$ contains a $k$-th root of $a$ so there are rational polynomials $C,D$ such that $C(x)^k-a=f(x)D(x)$.

Let $p$ be a large enough prime number such that the coefficients of $A,B,C,D$ are $p$-integers (ie they have a nonnegative $p$-adic valuation). Assume that there exists some integer $n$ such that $p|f(n)$. Then $p$ divides $\Phi_{k}(b)$ where $b$ is the reduction in $\mathbb{F}_p$ of $A(n)$, and $p$ divides $d^k-a$ where $d$ is the reduction in $\mathbb{F}_p$ of $C(n)$.

As in the old answer, we can conclude that $b$ has order $k$ mod $p$ (because $k \in (\Phi_k(x),\prod_{d|k}{\Phi_d(x)}) \supset (x^k-1,(x^k-1)’)$) and that $d$ is a $k$-th root of $a$ mod $p$.

---

**Old answer**: Right… this proof may be a little more sophisticated than what you may be comfortable with. It uses some nontrivial abstract algebra and algebraic number theory. Maybe there’s a simpler argument (did the article imply that there was an elementary proof?) – but I can believe otherwise too.

Let $K$ be the splitting field of the polynomial $x^k-a$, $d$ its degree, $D$ its absolute discriminant, $R$ its ring of integers, $\alpha \in R$ a primitive element with minimal (monic) polynomial $f$, $R_1=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, then let $p$ be a prime number coprime to $NDk$, where $N$ is the cardinality of the finite group $R/R_1$.

There are polynomials $g,h$ of degree at most $d-1$ with integer coefficients such that $g(\alpha)$ is $N$ times a $k$-th root of $a$, and $h(\alpha)$ is $N$ times a primitive $k$-th root of unity.

We claim that if $p$ divides $f(n)$ for some integer $n$, then $p$ works, and this concludes.

Indeed, if $\alpha-n$ is coprime to $p$ in $R$, then it is not in any prime ideal of $R$ above $p$, and thus neither are its Galois conjugates (the $\beta-n$ where $\beta$ is any root of $f$), and thus $f(n)=\prod_{\beta}{(\beta-n)}$ is in no prime ideal above $p$ so cannot be divisible by $p$.

Let $q \subset R$ be some prime ideal above $p$ such that $\alpha-n \in q$. We can see directly that $R_1/(R_1 \cap q) \rightarrow R/q$ is a bijection (it’s clearly injective, and the range has characteristic $p$ but its cokernel has a cardinality dividing $|R/R_1|=N$), and $R_1=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ with $\alpha-n \in q$, $q \cap \mathbb{Z}=p\mathbb{Z}$, so that $R_1/(q \cap R_1)=\mathbb{F}_p$.

Thus $g(n)$ is in $\mathbb{Z}$ and is congruent mod $q \cap R_1$ to $g(\alpha)$, so $g(n)^k$ is congruent to $N^ka$ mod $q \cap R_1 \cap \mathbb{Z}=p\mathbb{Z}$.

Finally, $y=h(n)$ is congruent mod $q \cap R_1$ to $h(\alpha)$, which is a root of $\Phi_{k,N}:=N^{\varphi(k)}\Phi_k(X/N)$, so $\Phi_{k,N}(h(n))$ is congruent mod $q \cap R_1 \cap \mathbb{Z}=p\mathbb{Z}$ to $0$.

Now, it is not hard to see that $n \in (x^n-1,(x^n-1)’)$, and thus that $n \in (\Phi_n,\prod{l|n, l<n}{\Phi_l})$, and thus $kN^{\varphi(k)} \in (\Phi_{k,N},\prod_{l|k,l < k}{\Phi_{l,N}})$.

It follows that in $\mathbb{F}_p$, $k$ is the order of $yN^{-1}$, so $p$ is congruent to $1$ mod $p$.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Yes, the article was entirely elementary and so I think the proposed problems should have elementary solutions too.But either way,at least I have one solution I guess.

Comment: @Teddy: you were right, there’s a solution that uses much lighter machinery (while not being entirely IMO-level either).

Answer (score 0):

I've found an elementary solution after all.

Rephrasing the question in terms of polynomials, it asks to prove that $\Phi_k(n)$ and $n^k-a$ share infinitely many prime divisors.

There is actually a theorem of Nagell that is a generalization of this:

**Theorem.** (Nagell) Let $f_1,...,f_n\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ nonconstant. Prove that there are infinitely many primes $p$ for which each $f_i$ has a root $\bmod p$.

*Proof*: The idea is to reduce the problem to the well-known Schur theorem, which is precisely this theorem for $n=1$.

As such, we will be looking for polynomials $g_1,...,g_n\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$ for which $f(g_i(X))$ all share some nonconstant divisor.
For this, let's fix $x_1,...,x_n\in\mathbb{C}$ some roots of $f_1,...,f_n$ and we search for some polynomials $g_i\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$ and $z\in\mathbb{C}$ s.t. $g_i(z)=x_i$, $\forall i\in\overline{1,n}$$\qquad (1)$.

Employing the primitive element theorem, notice that $x_i$ are all algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$ thus there is an algebraic number $z$ for which $\mathbb{Q}(x_1,...,x_n)=\mathbb{Q}(z)$, hence there exist polynomials $g_i$ that are satisfying (1). We can make $z$ into an algebraic integer by just multiplying it by a suitable integer.

Now, we need to resolve some integer issues. Firstly, take $N\in\mathbb{N^*}$ for which $h_i=Ng_i\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $d$ large enough such that $F_i(X)=N^df_i\left(\frac{h_i(X)}{N}\right)\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

The final step is to consider $P$ the minimal polynomial of $z$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. As $z$ is an algebraic integer, $P$ is monic. By Gauss's lemma, $F_i$'s are divisible by $P$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. Now we can just use Schur's theorem to find infinitely many prime divisors for $P$, and the theorem is proved.   $\square$